# if $f$ is continuous and $t \mapsto \partial_t f(x,t)$ is continuous then is $(x,t) \mapsto \partial_t f(x,t)$ continous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\partial_t f(x,t)$ exists and such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $t \mapsto \partial_t f(x,t)$ is continuous. Then is : 
>   $$(x,t) \mapsto \partial_t f(x,t)$$
>
> continuous ?

When doing an exercise on the continuity of integrales with parameters I am using this fact yet I don't know if this is true or false.

It feel like it's false but I wasn't able to find a counter-example.

Thank you !

Comment: It's false. You'll be able to come up with a counter-example when you think of classical examples of functions that are separately continuous, but not jointly continuous.

Comment: @MarsPlastic Thank you, I am going to look at those.